# Problem setting unique meta keywords for each page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, meta-tags

I am currently in the process of trying to add unique page titles and keywords to the pages on a website.  Previously I had set the title, keywords and description in the application layout but ideally i would like to be able to set these individually for each page.

Looking at previous questions, I found it was possible to set the title using the code below:

[In application layout]

```
<title><%=h yield(:title) %></title>
```

[In page view]

```
<% content_for :title, "Content here..." %>
```

This worked just as hoped.  However, I then tried to apply the same logic to the meta keywords:

```
<meta name="keywords" content=<%=h yield(:keywords) %> >

<% content_for :keywords, "word1, word2, word3" %>
```

This doesn't give an error, however, when I view the page source there are " missing, i.e. it appears as:

```
<meta name="keywords" content=word1, word2, word3 >
```

rather than

```
<meta name="keywords" content="word1, word2, word3">
```

Is there an easy way to remedy this, or am I barking up the wrong tree trying to do it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add quotes to your code:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<%=h yield(:keywords) %>">
```

Comment: Sorry that was one of the first things i tried and got an error, but trying again now it works with no problem... Thanks